# linux sshpass not able to execute command remotely

Tags: sshpass

I have remote `red-hat 5.4` machine where I am able to execute

> sudo lvdisplay

command locally using xyz user but while executing the same command remotely using xyz user through `sshpass`, I am getting the result as

> sudo: lvdisplay: command not found.

The command I am executing is like

> sshpass -p 'password' ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
>   xyz@hostname sudo lvdisplay

.

Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: off-topic. ask on unix and linux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
sshpass -p pass ssh -t user@192.168.XXX.XXX 'ls; bash -l'
```

Try the above command it worked for me. Remember to replace `pass` and `user`.

Comment: What if port number is different? Where I need to show it?

Comment: After ssh, use the P flag, i.e.
sshpass -p pass ssh -P 5555 user@abc.cde.efg.ghe 'ls; bash -l'